# Backing Up To Google Drive with Duplicity Not Working

Tags: backup, google-docs-api, duplicity, duplicity-backup

I'm trying to backup to Google Drive with Duplicity, and I can't seem to figure it out. I run this:

```
GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTINGS=gdrive duplicity / pydrive+gdocs://*******[:*********]@other.host/server-backup
```

and I get this:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 314, in LoadClientConfigFile
    raise InvalidConfigError('Invalid client secrets file %s' % error)
InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
```

I saved my client ID and client secret bits in the gdrive file (for GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTINGS), but no matter where I try, I cannot seem to figure out where to put the client_secrets.json file. I would appreciate any help in getting this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the manpage http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect22 says to give the settings filename as the GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTINGS env var. locationwise i would guess it would be placed in the current user's home folder. alternatively try setting an absolute path to the file.

make sure that the file is formatted as the manpage states.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: How do I give it as the GOOGLE_DRIVE_SETTING environment variable?

Comment: Oh, wait, I figured it out. Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm actually getting: Attempt 1 failed. "ApiRequestError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=multipart&alt=json returned "User rate limit exceeded">"

now. Any ideas on how to fix this? @ede The quota in Google APIs is set to 1 billion requests per day (which I've used 115 of, and 1,000 requests per user per 100 seconds...what I assume the culprit to be)...